# Adding custom customer attributes

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, customer-account

I know its possible to set custom customer attributes using various extensions however I haven't yet found one which suits my needs.

I need to allow customers to add multiple sets of the same attributes within their profile / my account - ,uch like how customers add multiple addresses.

I could of course add the following fields custom customer fields

set_1_field_1
set_1_field_2
set_1_field_3

set_2_field_1
set_2_field_2
set_2_field_3

However the issue with this is that I am hard coding in a limit of the amount of sets the customer is allowed to add. I would like the customer to be able to update their profile with no upper limit.

Could anyone suggest an extension that will help me or the best way to tackle this

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one, I think it will do whatever you need
https://amasty.com/customer-attributes.html